# As Part of JMeter WEB DRIVER(Selenium Scripts) Integration With Azure Pipeline and how can I add Headless Browser in Azure Pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, performance, jmeter-plugins, azure-devops, cicd

As Part of JMeter WEB DRIVER(Selenium Scripts) Integration With Azure Pipeline and how can I **add Headless Browser in Azure Pipeline**.

Someone suggested the link is https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/headless-browser-selenium-python but still I didn't get so can anyone suggest me the step by steps procedure on Azure Pipeline please?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to be correct, you just made a typo

It should be

```
jpgc-webdriver
```

and you have

```
jpgc -webdriver
```

Remove this whitespace and it should be successful.

---

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: Thanks Drimiti for your help! Could you please help me how can I add Headless Browser in Azure Pipeline please and also it helps me if you can share the any youtuve video or step by step procedure.TIA!